# jQuery check if input text contains specific text

Tags: jquery, input, append, contains

If input text field contains "**@twitter.com**", would like to append text to `div`.

Currently have the following but only works when `test=151516058@twitter.com`, any suggestions?

```
var test = jQuery('input[name$="user_email"]').val(); 
  if(test == "@twitter.com"){
     jQuery(".iump-clear").append('<div>Please update your email address</div>');
  }

<input type="text" name="user_email" value="151516058@twitter.com">
<div class="iump-clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if @twitter.com is contained in input, you can use `.indexOf()` for that

```
var test = jQuery('input[name$="user_email"]').val(); 
  if(test.indexOf("@twitter.com")>-1){
     jQuery(".iump-clear").append('<div>Please update your email address</div>');
  }

<input type="text" name="user_email" value="151516058@twitter.com">
<div class="iump-clear"></div>
```

Comment: That worked! I wasn't familiar with indexOf(), thanks a lot!

Comment: Or using a Regex: /@twitter.com$/i.test(test)