# Disabling a button after certain input in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so this textbox disables the `play button` upon inputting values of @ ,*, -, _, etc.

Text Box Code / Input Box Code:

```
<input id="nick" class="form-control input-lg no-border spaced" placeholder="Name" maxlength="15">
```

Play Button Code :  
                    
                       Play

```
                  <a id="spectate-btn" onclick="spectate(); return false;" class="click btn btn-warning full-width expand spaced" type="submit">Spectate</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery check if input text contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455128/jquery-check-if-input-text-contains-specific-text)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider:

1) This is an anchor, so just setting the `disabled` attribute is not gonna cut it.

2) You are using Vanilla JavaScript.

Here is an attempt:

```js
var disableKeys = ['@', '*', '-', '_'];
window.onload = setEvent;

function setEvent() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('spectate-btn');
  document.getElementById("nick").onkeyup = function(c) {
    if (disableKeys.includes(c.key)) {
      btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      btn.className += " button-disabled";
    }
  }
}

function spectate() {
 alert("This is working!");
}
```

```css
.button-disabled {
       pointer-events: none !important;
       cursor: default;
       color:Gray;
}
```

```html
<input id="nick" class="form-control input-lg no-border spaced" placeholder="Name" maxlength="15">
                  <a id="spectate-btn" href="#" onclick="spectate(); return false;" class="click btn btn-warning full-width expand spaced" type="submit">Spectate</a>
```

Notice that this adds a css class to simulate the button is disabled. I also added my own function to simulate your spectate function, and to show the button is truly disabled.

The way it works I hook the function on the `keyup` event of the textbox. Every time a character is typed I check was character it is (so copy/paste, and other events are special cases that you might have to handle). I have an array with all of the characters you mention. You  could add more chars to this array.

Since you don't mention it, I do not handle when the character is removed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,, I've used regex to target no alpha letters, but you can specify only chars that you want and delimit them with pipe ( | )
Because you are using bootstrap, just add `disabled` and bootstrap will do the rest and disable it for you

```js
$('input.form-control').on( 'input', function(el){
  var str = $(this).val();
  // I'm targeting any symbol that is not letter but you can specify 
  // each char that you want,, like this: /@|*|-|+/g
  if( str.match( /[^a-z|A-Z]/g ) != null ) {
    // if match is found disable button
    $('a').attr('disabled', 'disabled') ;
  } else {
    $('a').removeAttr('disabled') ;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="nick" class="form-control input-lg no-border spaced" placeholder="Name" maxlength="15">

<a id="spectate-btn" onclick="spectate(); return false;" class="click btn btn-warning full-width expand spaced" type="submit">Spectate</a>
```